# Subtract 10000 from only large elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, subtraction

I have an array called "array", which is size (45, 41), which should contain values in the range (-200, 200). However, some of the values have been 'tagged' by the addition of 10,000 to their value. I want to detag those elements by: subtracting 10000 if the element in question is greater than 8000 (if it's greater than 8000 it must be tagged).

So essentially, in pseudocode, I wish to:

```
for i in 1:45
    for j in 1:41
        if array[i,j] > 8000
            array[i,j] = array[i,j] - 10000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here is my full code:

```
#Read file
cubes=iris.load(pathfile)
print cubes
wind=cubes[0]
print wind

#Select the month
wind_cut = wind[11, :, :, 0]
array=wind_cut.data

print array.shape

for i in 1:45
    for j in 1:41
        if array[i,j] > 8000
            array[i,j] = array[i,j] - 10000
```

All I get is an indent error. I'm new to python and this site, sorry if I'm being a noob.

Comment: Are these arrays numpy arrays?

Comment: where's your non-pseudocode? what's the problem?

Comment: So what were the problems when you tried to express it in python? You did try it, didn't you?

Comment: Yes I think it's a numpy array. I took it from a cube:
#Read file
cubes=iris.load(pathfile)
print cubes
wind=cubes[0]
print wind

#Select the month
wind_cut = wind[11, :, :, 0]
array=wind_cut.data

And I don't know how to code it properly! When I put in the above code I get an 'unexpected indent' error. Should my pseudocode make sense in python?

Comment: Ok, you are new to this site. But remember for a next time : **ALWAYS GIVE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE** immediately. Python is very strict about indentation and a common mistake for beginners is to mix spaces and tabs in source code. `idle` is you friend : it allows you to press `tab` key and kindly convert it to spaces.

Comment: missing tons of colons...

Comment: Ok Serge, sorry will do next time. And yes qarma it might have worked with colons!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with numpy arrays, try this:

```
array[array>8000] -= 10000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't expect it to be so simple!

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, a condition like nparray>=N creates an array of true/false we can use as an index.

```
import numpy
nparray = numpy.array(array) # reads a regular array and makes a numpy array
nparray[nparray>=8000] -=  10000  # subtract 10000 from the elements over 8000 only
# result in nparray
```